# Know which WM is used from a shell

Tags: bash, window-managers

(On a Linux, for a shell running in a terminal emulator in a graphical server,) I'm interested in knowing how to determine in which Window manager the shell is running.
Thanks

(I want that for my .bashrc)

Comment: One (possibly error-prone) way that comes to mind is simply inspecting the output of `ps`.

Comment: It doesn't work, sorry. Moreover, using process names can't work with multiple x-servers running.

Comment: Is any of the information here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running helpful?

Comment: @ioxaxs You could look for process tree `ps axf` for following hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wmctrl -m | grep Name | cut -d: -f2` seems to give the right answer.  But it is not necessarily installed.

`xlsclients` lists all X clients in the current display (including the window manager) which may be useful, but you'll need to know a list of possible window managers to make a positive identification.  e.g

```
xlsclients | grep -e compiz -e xfwm4
```

Comment: wmctrl works, but xlsclients doesn't include the WM "awesome".
Thanks